# Finding the length of object array, where value is not-empty

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a method that outputs an Excel range as an `object[,]`:

```
    static public Excel.Workbook OpenWorksheetAsReadOnly(string filePath)
    {
        Excel.Application excelInstance = null;

        // Open workbook as readOnly, update links
        excelInstance = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelInstance.Workbooks.
                                       Open(filePath, true, true);

        return excelWorkbook;
    }

static public object[,] ImportExcelIntoArray(string filePath)
    {
        Excel.Workbook source = null;
        source = OpenWorksheetAsReadOnly(filePath);

        Excel.Range sourceRange = source.Sheets[1].Range("B1:D1000");
        object[,] sourceValues = (object[,])sourceRange.Value2;

        return sourceValues;
    }
```

I know that my output array is 1000 rows long. I also know that not all those rows will be filled, and I know that the source document gets filled from top to bottom.

In another method I would like to iterate over the rows, but to save time, I would only like to iterate over the number of **actually-filled** rows. Ideally, I'd use (where `excelObject` is the output of the above method):

```
int rowCount = excelObject.Count(x => x != null);
```

However, it doesn't work for type `object[*,*]` — I think it would work for a `List`. I have had a look here and I have seen `excelObject.Length`, but that just gives me the number of cells in the object in total.

Is there any way to do this? Do I need to change the type from `object` to something else? The values in the cells are both strings and floats, so I'd like to keep it without type-specifying as long as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the 2d array implements the non generic [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, you you could use the [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to convert it to `IEnumerable<T>` and then apply the desired LINQ operators on it:

```
int rowCount = excelObject.Cast<object>().Count(x => x != null);
```

But please note that the above actually counts the non empty *cells*. If you really want to count the non empty *rows*, you could use `Enumerable.Range` for generating row/column indices into the source array:

```
var rowCount = Enumerable.Range(0, excelObject.GetLength(0))
    .Count(row => Enumerable.Range(0, excelObject.GetLength(1))
        .Any(col => excelObject[row, col] != null));
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a small comment, `excelObject` is 1-indexed, so the `Enumerable.Range` has to have the initial argument of `1` not `0`, at least in my case